# Retain a row based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 account_id contract_id status
0   AAA 123 Active
1   AAA 456 Inactive
2   AAA 912 Active
3   BB  462 Inactive
4   BB  821 Inactive
```

I want the following output:

```
 account_id status
0   AAA Active
1   BB  Inactive
```

The condition for this is that I need the status for each account and if at least one contract for that account is "Active" then the account will be considered as "Active". If all the contracts for the account is "Inactive", then the account will be considered as "Inactive".

Comment: @jezrael The linked dupe is incorrect.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - oops, ypu are right, need `df = df.sort_values('status').drop_duplicates('account_id')`

Comment: @jezrael yeah that might work assuming there is no other category in status apart from `Active` and `Inactive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only `Active` and `Inactive` values in `status` column use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['account_id','status']).drop_duplicates('account_id')[['account_id','status']]
print (df)
  account_id    status
1        AAA    Active
3         BB  Inactive
```

If not first use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for set non `Active, Inactive` to missing values:

```
s = df['status'].where(df['status'].isin(['Active', 'Inactive']))
df = df.assign(status=s).sort_values(['account_id','status']).drop_duplicates('account_id')[['account_id','status']]
print (df)
  account_id    status
1        AAA    Active
3         BB  Inactive
```

---

Another idea is aggregate `min`:

```
#non `Active, Inactive` are set to missing values
df['status'] = df['status'].where(df['status'].isin(['Active', 'Inactive']))
df = df.groupby('account_id', as_index=False)['status'].min()
print (df)
  account_id    status
0        AAA    Active
1         BB  Inactive
```