# Change the dataframe based on a condition from the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My data is as follows:

```
 account_id contract_id status
0   AAA 123 Inactive
1   AAA 456 Active
2   AAA 912 Inactive
3   BB  462 Inactive
4   BB  821 Inactive
```

I want the following result:

```
 account_id status
0   AAA Active
1   BB  Inactive
```

Each account can have more than one contracts as shown under "contract_id". If at least one contract for the same account is "Active" then the account will be considered as "Active". If all contracts for the same account is "Inactive" then the account will be considered as "Inactive".

Comment: There is only `Active` and `Inactive` values in `status`?

Comment: The [`same question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485064/retain-a-row-based-on-a-condition?noredirect=1) has been asked 2 mins ago, Is that a coincidence?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - I think some colegaues

Comment: @jezrael May be mark this question as a dupe and you can give answer in the previously asked question because one of the question needs to be closed .

Answer (score 1):

If only `Active` and `Inactive` values in `status` column use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['account_id','status']).drop_duplicates('account_id')[['account_id','status']]
print (df)
  account_id    status
1        AAA    Active
3         BB  Inactive
```

If not first use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for set non `Active, Inactive` to missing values:

```
s = df['status'].where(df['status'].isin(['Active', 'Inactive']))
df = df.assign(status=s).sort_values(['account_id','status']).drop_duplicates('account_id')[['account_id','status']]
print (df)
  account_id    status
1        AAA    Active
3         BB  Inactive
```

---

Another idea is aggregate `min`:

```
#non `Active, Inactive` are set to missing values
df['status'] = df['status'].where(df['status'].isin(['Active', 'Inactive']))
df = df.groupby('account_id', as_index=False)['status'].min()
print (df)
  account_id    status
0        AAA    Active
1         BB  Inactive
```